# Import in node js file for aws lambda function is not working when I deployed it with serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, slack-api

So I was trying to build a slack app and deploy it to aws. I built the app and it works fine but when I try and create other js files to import them in my main, the aws post url doesn't work.

The structure of my project(app) is:

```
Slack-app:
----------- app.js
----------- app_home.js
----------- package.json
----------- package-lock.json
----------- serverless.yml
```

..... The others are node_modules, .serverless etc.

So basically, without the import of app_home.js, the code works when deployed to aws lambda. On the slack app, it sends a message back when you type in hello. But when I add an import, the whole thing, doesn't work.

This works:

```
"use strict";

const { App, AwsLambdaReceiver, WorkflowStep } = require('@slack/bolt');


// Initialize your custom receiver
const awsLambdaReceiver = new AwsLambdaReceiver({
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});

// Initializes your app with your bot token and the AWS Lambda ready receiver
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  receiver: awsLambdaReceiver,
  // The `processBeforeResponse` option is required for all FaaS environments.
  // It allows Bolt methods (e.g. `app.message`) to handle a Slack request
  // before the Bolt framework responds to the request (e.g. `ack()`). This is
  // important because FaaS immediately terminate handlers after the response.
  processBeforeResponse: true
});

// Listens to incoming messages that contain "hello"
app.message('hello', async ({ message, say }) => {
  // say() sends a message to the channel where the event was triggered
  await say({
    text: `Hey there <@${message.user}>! \n Have any questions or concerns, Please contact the IT team.`
  });
});

// Handle the Lambda function event
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const handler = await awsLambdaReceiver.start();
  return handler(event, context, callback);
}
```

Where as, this doesn't work at all:

```
"use strict";

const { App, AwsLambdaReceiver, WorkflowStep } = require('@slack/bolt');

// THIS IS THE LINE THAT I CHANGED FROM THE PREVIOUS CODE
const app_home = require('./app_home')

// Initialize your custom receiver
const awsLambdaReceiver = new AwsLambdaReceiver({
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});

// Initializes your app with your bot token and the AWS Lambda ready receiver
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  receiver: awsLambdaReceiver,
  // The `processBeforeResponse` option is required for all FaaS environments.
  // It allows Bolt methods (e.g. `app.message`) to handle a Slack request
  // before the Bolt framework responds to the request (e.g. `ack()`). This is
  // important because FaaS immediately terminate handlers after the response.
  processBeforeResponse: true
});

// Listens to incoming messages that contain "hello"
app.message('hello', async ({ message, say }) => {
  // say() sends a message to the channel where the event was triggered
  await say({
    text: `Hey there <@${message.user}>! \n Have any questions or concerns, Please contact the IT team.`
  });
});

// Handle the Lambda function event
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const handler = await awsLambdaReceiver.start();
  return handler(event, context, callback);
}
```

So, I was just working, if it is a deployment issue?

My code for serverless is:

```
service: slack-app-bolt-js-forto
frameworkVersion: '2'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  profile: default
  timeout: 5
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  memorySize: 512
  environment:
    SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET: ${env:SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET}
    SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${env:SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}

functions:
  slack:
    handler: app.handler
    memorySize: 1536
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: slack/events
          method: post
          
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "bolt-js-getting-started-app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Getting Started ⚡️ Bolt for JavaScript",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ngrok": "ngrok http 3000",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "^3.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless": "^2.59.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the error you are receiving?

Comment: Could you add some details on how you are deploying to lambda and the contents of app_home.js ?